# Convert datatable/datarow[] column to int from string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have a datatable with a column called "position" that is coming across as strings. I use DataTable.Select to get a list of data rows.

```
DataRow[] drTopMenu = dtMenuItems.Select("ParentMenuID is null", "Position asc");
```

However, the positions are 1, 2, ..., 9, 10 and data row array comes sorted as 1, 10, 2, 3, ..., 9.
How can I fix this? Is there a way I can change the data type of "Position" column from string to int before filtering/sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the efficiency, and this assumes that the position column will always contain an int.

```
DataRow[] drTopMenu = dtMenuItems
                .Select("ParentMenuID is null")
                .OrderBy(x => int.Parse((string)x["Position"]))
                .ToArray();
```